# Symbolic evaluation of the double series with terms $1/[a^2 + (b + m)^2 + (c+n)^2]$

Tags: summation

Any chance to sum this series? ($a,b,c$ are real)

```
Sum[((a^2 + (b + m)^2) + (c + n)^2)^(-1), {n, -∞, ∞}, {m, -∞, ∞}]
```

Or even a more general one?

```
Sum[((a^2 + (b + d m)^2) + (c + e n)^2)^(-1), {n, -∞, ∞}, {m, -∞, ∞}]
```

I don't know if it can help, but the sum of

```
Sum[((a^2 + (b + n)^2))^(-1), {n, -∞, ∞}]
```

is

$$\frac{\pi  \sinh (2 \pi  a)}{a (\cosh (2 \pi  a)-\cos (2 \pi  b))}.$$

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: The sum logarithmic diverges. More precisely, $\sum_{m^2 + n^2 < r^2} ( \cdots ) \sim O(\log r)$